# I am trying export data in excel sheet from mysqli database but I am unable to serialize the S No like 1,2,3..etc in multiple sheets?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpexcel

[image: Updated screenshot]Below is my code. I do want to serialize the S No as I am getting the S No as per the DB.I am attaching the screenshot of excel file as well.Any help would be great for me.[![I have provided my query in the image itself.
Hope you have got question. 
[[image: Have written the query in pic.]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqRVK.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOZKN.png)

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "ON");
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");

$xls_filename = 'Data' . date('d-m-Y') . '.xls'; // Define Excel (.xls) file name
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Programming');
$heading = array(
    'id' => 'S.No',
    'name' => 'Name',
    'dept' => 'Department',

);

$no_of_cols = count($heading);
$rowNumberH = 1;
$colH = 'A';
$columns = array('0' => 'A', '1' => 'B', '2' => 'C', '3' => 'D', '4' => 'E', '5' => 'F', '6' => 'G', '7' => 'H', '8' => 'I', '9' => 'J', '10' => 'K', '11' => 'L', '12' => 'M', '13' => 'N', '14' => 'O', '15' => 'P', '16' => 'Q', '17' => 'R', '18' => 'S', '19' => 'T', '20' => 'U', '21' => 'V', '22' => 'W', '23' => 'X', '24' => 'Y', '25' => 'Z');

$q = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM form where dept='programming'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {
    foreach ($heading as $h) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($colH . $rowNumberH, $h);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($colH)->setWidth(25);
        $colH++;
    }
    $row = 2;
    while ($row_q = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $i = 0;
       $cnt=1;
        foreach ($row_q as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'location')
                continue;
                if($key == 'id')
            {
              $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columns[$i] . $row, $cnt);
            }else {

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columns[$i] . $row, $row_q[$key]);
}
            $i++;
        }$cnt++;
       $row++;
    }
}
/*--------------------2nd sheet-----------------------------*/
//$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Graphics');
$heading = array(
    'id' => 'S.No',
    'name' => 'Name',
    'dept' => 'Department',

);

$no_of_cols = count($heading);
$rowNumberH = 1;
$colH = 'A';
$columns = array('0' => 'A', '1' => 'B', '2' => 'C', '3' => 'D', '4' => 'E', '5' => 'F', '6' => 'G', '7' => 'H', '8' => 'I', '9' => 'J', '10' => 'K', '11' => 'L', '12' => 'M', '13' => 'N', '14' => 'O', '15' => 'P', '16' => 'Q', '17' => 'R', '18' => 'S', '19' => 'T', '20' => 'U', '21' => 'V', '22' => 'W', '23' => 'X', '24' => 'Y', '25' => 'Z');

$q = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM form where dept='graphics'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {
    foreach ($heading as $h) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($colH . $rowNumberH, $h);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($colH)->setWidth(25);
        $colH++;
    }
    $row = 2;
    while ($row_q = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($row_q as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'location')
                continue;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columns[$i] . $row, $row_q[$key]);
            $i++;
        }$row++;
    }
}
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$xls_filename");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update this part & try:

```
    while ($row_q = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            $i = 0;$cnt=1;
            foreach ($row_q as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == 'location')
                    continue;
                if($key == 'id')
                {
                  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columns[$i] . $row, $cnt);
                }
                else {

                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columns[$i] . $row, $row_q[$key]);
    }
                $i++;
            }
$cnt++; //this part is missing
            $row++;
        }
```

Comment: the values of $cnt is not incrementing.. why is it so?

Comment: check at the end of `foreach()`

Comment: Already tried but values are not incrementing, it is printing only 1 in every row

Comment: I have uploaded an image after changing as per your comment also its not working..

Comment: same as mentioned by you.

Comment: Please update your while loop same as mine....you have missed the `if($key == 'id')` block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110951/discussion-between-deepak-jawalkar-and-dipanwita-kundu).

Comment: have updated the code. Would you please revert me back in chat of stackoverflow..

Answer (score 1):

With the help and support of Dipanwita I am finally posting my answer..
I have done the solution for 1st sheet can be done same for 2nd as well.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "ON");
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");

$xls_filename = 'Data' . date('d-m-Y') . '.xls'; // Define Excel (.xls) file name
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Programming');
$heading = array(
    'id' => 'S.No',
    'name' => 'Name',
    'dept' => 'Department',

);

$no_of_cols = count($heading);
$rowNumberH = 1;
$colH = 'A';
$columns = array('0' => 'A', '1' => 'B', '2' => 'C', '3' => 'D', '4' => 'E', '5' => 'F', '6' => 'G', '7' => 'H', '8' => 'I', '9' => 'J', '10' => 'K', '11' => 'L', '12' => 'M', '13' => 'N', '14' => 'O', '15' => 'P', '16' => 'Q', '17' => 'R', '18' => 'S', '19' => 'T', '20' => 'U', '21' => 'V', '22' => 'W', '23' => 'X', '24' => 'Y', '25' => 'Z');

$q = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM form where dept='programming'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {
    foreach ($heading as $h) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($colH . $rowNumberH, $h);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($colH)->setWidth(25);
        $colH++;
    }
    $row = 2;
    while ($row_q = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $i = 0;
        //$cnt = 1;
        foreach ($row_q as $key => $value) 
        {
            if ($key == 'location')
                continue;
            if($key == 'id')
            {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columns[$i] . $row, $row-1);
            }
            else 
            {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columns[$i] . $row, $row_q[$key]);
            }
            //var_dump($cnt);

            //alert($cnt);
            $i++;
            //$cnt++;
        }       
        $row++;

    }
}
/*--------------------2nd sheet-----------------------------*/
//$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Graphics');
$heading = array(
    'id' => 'S.No',
    'name' => 'Name',
    'dept' => 'Department',

);

$no_of_cols = count($heading);
$rowNumberH = 1;
$colH = 'A';
$columns = array('0' => 'A', '1' => 'B', '2' => 'C', '3' => 'D', '4' => 'E', '5' => 'F', '6' => 'G', '7' => 'H', '8' => 'I', '9' => 'J', '10' => 'K', '11' => 'L', '12' => 'M', '13' => 'N', '14' => 'O', '15' => 'P', '16' => 'Q', '17' => 'R', '18' => 'S', '19' => 'T', '20' => 'U', '21' => 'V', '22' => 'W', '23' => 'X', '24' => 'Y', '25' => 'Z');

$q = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM form where dept='graphics'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0) {
    foreach ($heading as $h) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($colH . $rowNumberH, $h);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($colH)->setWidth(25);
        $colH++;
    }
    $row = 2;
    while ($row_q = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($row_q as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'location')
                continue;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columns[$i] . $row, $row_q[$key]);
            $i++;
        }$row++;
    }
}
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$xls_filename");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

Comment: This code example really helped me out.  Thank You!